# How do I change IAR Workbench to use a dark theme?

Tags: iar

I want to change the theme of IAR Workbench to a dark one. Another post says it uses Windows' theme. I just changed Windows 10 to dark mode, but IAR is still light.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to set IAR Workbench to a darker theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've only ever been able to alter the color theme manually within Tools->Options->Editor->Colors and Fonts.

Comment: I believe that's the only way to edit the color theme in IAR.  It's color theme appears to be totally independent of the host OS.